# Bind multiple controls to collections in MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have 10 text type input controls, 5 on first tab & 5 on second tab on same page.

Now I have a class as

```
public partial class TravelerMaster
{
     public virtual ICollection<TravelerDetail> TravelerDetails { get; set; }
}
```

which has a collection as TravelerDetail.

```
public partial class TravelerDetail
{
    public byte PackageTypeId { get; set; }
    public int? NoOfPackage { get; set; }
    public decimal? Weight { get; set; }
    public decimal? PricePerKg { get; set; }
    public decimal? PricePerPackage { get; set; }
}
```

How do i bind the controls such that when I post the data, the TravelerMaster object has two objects in its collection.

Please help me. Thanks in advance. Feel free to ask any query.

Comment: Could you please specify why you down voted ?

Comment: You should you specify questions, e.g provide code.

Comment: It was not me who downvoted, but your question lacks of signs of self-effort. Do you know anything about Bindings? What have you tried so far?

Comment: Yeah i am just editing it as you said.

Comment: @Dave: Yes i know about binding. And i am editing my question and adding the code which i have come up with yet

Comment: @Mediator: Thanx for guiding.

Comment: If you only have 2 items, then having 2 properties e.g. `TravelerDetail First` and `TravelerDetail Second` would be easiest, otherwise you will need to change you property to `IList<TravelerDetail>` so you can use indexing.

Comment: Yeah i have multiple items actually

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can submit a collection of a particular model like this. By applying an index (this can be anything unique but I've used an integer value for ease) you can submit a collection of the same model to the controller:

**Form**

```
<div id="tab1">
     @Html.Hidden("data.Index","1")
     @Html.TextBox("data[1].weight", "", new { @class = "your-class-names", @id = "data[1].weight" })
     ...other fields...
</div>
<div id="tab2">
     @Html.Hidden("data.Index","2")
     @Html.TextBox("data[2].weight", "", new { @class = "your-class-names", @id = "data[2].weight" })
     ...other fields...
</div>
```

***Controller***

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult YourControllerMethod(IEnumerable<TravelerDetail> data)
{
     if (data==null || data.Count() == 0) throw new Exception("No Data Added");
     ....other validation...
     foreach(var item in data) {
         ...database work...
     }
}
```

Comment: Ok thanx, lemme try this code and get back to you again

Comment: @MurtazaMunshi glad to be of assistance

Comment: Do not set the `id` attribute that way. The html helper will create it correctly (as `id="data_1__weight"`) This way it will contains the `[`, `]` and `.` characters which means any attempt to use then with jquery it will fail!

Comment: So if i dont specify Id in html Attributes it will be automatically created right.

Comment: I've never had an issue the way I've described above and I always use jquery to both dynamically load partial views containing each instance of the form in question like this and submit the forms back to the controller

Comment: @MurtazaMunshi, Yes, the helpers will automatically add the**correct** `id` attribute. Do not attempt to overwrite them this way - if you ever had any jquery referring to these elements it would fail - for example the `.` (dor) would be interpreted the the start of a class name)

Comment: @StephenMuecke: +1 for the info you provided.